# Observer Observables implementing issue

Tags: java, android

I've been reading up on the Observer Pattern for keeping my UI up to date but I still can't get it to work, As far as I understand the Observer is my UI and it watches my Pet class for any variable changes if there is any it runs update(); At the minute it does nothing, not even Log.d.

Observer/MainActivity

```
package com.grim.droidchi;

import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Observer, OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "VPET";
    private static final String APP_PREFS = "VPET";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    TextView happiness_display, health_display, hunger_display, level_display;
    Button PunchPet, UpdateHunger;
    public static Pet pet = new Renamon();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.pet_display);
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/renamon.gif");
        myWebView.setInitialScale(10000);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);


        PunchPet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.PunchPet);
        UpdateHunger = (Button) findViewById(R.id.UpdateHunger);
        final TextView hunger_display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hunger_display);
        TextView happiness_display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.happiness_display);
        TextView level_display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.level_display);
        TextView health_display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.health_display);

        hunger_display.setText(Integer.toString(pet.getHunger()));
        health_display.setText(Integer.toString(pet.getHP()));
        level_display.setText(Integer.toString(pet.getLVL()));
        happiness_display.setText(Integer.toString(pet.getHappy()));


        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Gameloop.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getBaseContext(), REQUEST_CODE, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis() + (5 * 1000), 1800000, pendingIntent);
        // 1800000 ms = 30 mins

        pet.feed();
        pet.addObserver(this);
        pet.notifyObservers(pet);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {


        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object data) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "soemthing has changed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == PunchPet) {
            pet.setLVL(50);
            pet.notifyObservers(pet);
            Log.d(TAG, "PUNCHPET" + pet.getHP());

    }else {

    }



    }

}
```

Observable/Pet

```
package com.grim.droidchi;

import java.util.Observable;


import android.util.Log;

public class Pet extends Observable implements PetInterface {

    private static final String TAG = "VPET";
    private int Health = 100;

    private int Happiness = 10;
    private int Level = 1;
    private int Hunger = 0;
    private int Exp = 0;
    private String Name;
    private Boolean isAlive = true;
    private Boolean isSick = false;

    public void setisAlive(boolean answer) {
        this.isAlive = answer;
    }

    public void setisSick(boolean answer) {
        this.isAlive = answer;
    }

    public void setHP(int hp) {
        this.Health = hp;
        notifyObservers(hp);
    }

    public void setLVL(int lvl) {
        this.Level = lvl;
        notifyObservers(lvl);
    }

    public void setXP(int xp) {
        this.Exp = xp;
        notifyObservers(xp);
    }

    public void setHunger(int hunger) {
        this.Hunger = hunger;
        notifyObservers(hunger);
    }

    public void setHappy(int happy) {
        this.Happiness = happy;
        notifyObservers(happy);
    }

    public int getHP() {

        return Health;
    }

    public int getLVL() {

        return Level;
    }

    public int getXP() {

        return Exp;
    }

    public int getHunger() {

        return Hunger;
    }

    public int getHappy() {

        return Happiness;
    }

    public boolean isAlive() {
        return isAlive;

    }

    public boolean isSick() {
        return isSick;

    }

    @Override
    public void sleep() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void clean() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void feed() {
        Log.d(TAG, "FEEDING FROM INTERFACE THING");

    }

    @Override
    public void passtime() {

    }

}
```

Yes I've asked this also but as you know, It got two answers (which although they maybe be right don't help me) and won't recieve anymore now it'll dropped too far down the list, If I could delete it I would

Logcat

```
02-25 22:51:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(12026): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-25 22:51:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(12026): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-25 22:51:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at com.grim.droidchi.MainActivity.update(MainActivity.java:93)
02-25 22:51:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at java.util.Observable.notifyObservers(Observable.java:138)
02-25 22:51:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at com.grim.droidchi.Pet.setHP(Pet.java:33)
02-25 22:51:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at com.grim.droidchi.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)
02-25 22:51:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
02-25 22:51:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
02-25 22:51:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-25 22:51:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-25 22:51:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-25 22:51:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5191)
02-25 22:51:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-25 22:51:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-25 22:51:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
02-25 22:51:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
02-25 22:51:50.381: E/AndroidRuntime(12026):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You are using eg. `notifyObservers(hunger)`. Where is this method?

Comment: Why are you overriding all the `Observable` methods and trying to keep track of the `Observers` yourself?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean? Must I have a method for variable? I thought the idea was if something changes (doesn't matter what) Observable lets Observer know then Observer can run update and just 'refresh' the textviews with new values?

Comment: @BrianRoach because this is how I was told it should be done, I think its a case of too many cooks, everyone tries there own take on explaining with more relate-able names after while they lose all meaning.

Comment: @Pheonix2105 The `Observable` class already does all of that.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean ... but ok. You really shouldn't have any of that code in your class. You just extend `Observable` and *use* the parent methods in your class. The fact that you're using a static field to hold your `Pet` makes it even more confusing.

Comment: Because at the minute I'm trying to understand one concept and get it working, Why the critique out of context? I do appreciate the help of anyone smarter/wiser/older/more experienced such as yourself but I am not a Java or Android programmer I am doing this to learn something and a lot of the things are over my head but I get there eventually. The particular reason thats there is so I could update the TextViews with the Pet.getHP(); etc, This probably wrong but one problem at a time :P. Thank you for replying though.~
.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If I extend Observables it places the three methods in my class which was as I understood it normal behaviour, Am incorrect?

Comment: @Pheonix2105, you don't need to override anything, the functionality is already there.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Could you please tell me if the code is correct now? I will update Main Question, Also could you answer separately so I can select your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you inherit from [`Observable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html), your class inherits all of its functionality. You don't need to override its methods or keep your own Set of `Observers` unless your adding your own functionality.  As `Bailey S` has stated, in your setter methods, before calling `notifyOservers()`, call `setChanged()`.

Try removing all the methods you've overridden from the `Observable` class. Also, every time you call `notifyObservers(object)`, call `clearChanged()` afterwards.

Comment: I've edited again after taking your advice, Nearly every other thing I've read or watched said I must implement the methods myself, it's still not working but starting to make more sense, now the update method does not get called nothing shows up in my Log.

Comment: to clarify I've still not really figured this out (help would still be nice but wouldn't blame you if you ran) but I've accepted your answer because you were the most helpful and least hostile and I genuinely appreciate that.

Comment: It probably has something to do with your `PunchPet` view and the `onClick` method because Observer-Observable is setup right.

Comment: The setup is not correct, you ***absolutely must call `setChanged()` before `notifyObservers()`***

Comment: Also a big thank you to you @SotiriosDelimanolis.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you have overriden `notifyObservers()`, but not `notifyObservers(java.lang.Object)`. You are calling the latter, but you didn't define it.

```
    @Override
    public void notifyObservers(Object o) {
        observers.notify(o);
        super.notifyObservers(o);
    }
```

Additionally, you internally might change the values, but the Observer doesn't know. Call `setChanged()` on your "pet" (Observable) to fix that.

Comment: It's unclear why he would override it or any of those, actually. I didn't even think to look / notice it.